# Download a file from sharepoint

Tags: c#, visual-studio, sharepoint

I am trying to download a file from sharepoint, I have this code and throw error code 500.

```
       static void DownloadFile(){
        string serverFilePath = "Here goes my URL, that open the file from any tab";
        var password = new SecureString();
        foreach (char c in Configuration.password) {
            password.AppendChar(c);
        }
        //  theese are the credentials and work fine because I tested in another method
        var o365credentials = new SharePointOnlineCredentials(Configuration.userName, password);

        var url = string.Format("{0}/{1}", Configuration.siteUrl, serverFilePath);
        //  My destination folder
        string destPath = @"C:\publisher";
        var request = System.Net.HttpWebRequest.Create(url);
        request.Credentials = o365credentials;
        using (var sReader = new StreamReader(request.GetResponse().GetResponseStream())) {
            using (var sWriter = new StreamWriter(destPath)) {
                sWriter.Write(sReader.ReadToEnd());
            }
        }
    }
```

Comment: do you have a question, or are you looking for someone to write your code for you?

Comment: Of course it is just a question, but the thing that I need is to know what method to call for downloading the file, or the parameters, some example for me to guide

Answer (score 6, accepted):

you can achieve this task  using `WebRequest` in order to download files from sharepoint site:

```
public void DownloadFile(string serverFilePath, string destPath)
{
    var url = string.Format("{0}/{1}", ServerURL, serverFilePath);
    Directory.CreateDirectory(Path.GetDirectoryName(destPath)); // this method creates your directory
    var request = System.Net.HttpWebRequest.Create(url);
    request.Credentials = System.Net.CredentialCache.DefaultCredentials;
    using (var sReader = new StreamReader(request.GetResponse().GetResponseStream()))
    {
        using (var sWriter = new StreamWriter(destPath))
        {
            sWriter.Write(sReader.ReadToEnd());
        }
    }
}
```

if you wish to use the `Client-object-model` you read that:
[How to get a file using SharePoint Client Object Model with only an absolute url at hand?](https://sharepoint.stackexchange.com/questions/62087/how-to-get-a-file-using-sharepoint-client-object-model-with-only-an-absolute-url)

Edit: fixed the spelling of CreateDirectory call

Comment: The point in all this is that i know from c#, but not from SharePoint, so I need please that you explain to me what do you mean with serverFilePath. Credentials I supose that mean the ClienContext. Please take a look to my code. sorry for everything

Comment: your code is using Client-object-model and i have added a really informative link if you wish to use it. the alternative way (my answer) is to use webrequest class, serverFilePath is just the path of the file and Credentials  are the network user and password. the createDirectiory() method you will have to create yourself - just a method that creates a path (folder) on the client pc , the file will be downloaded to that path.

Comment: Now I understand better, but it throw me an error number 500, it is really frustrating this stuff of sharepoing, sorry for all

Comment: How can we download without specifying the destination path.

Comment: could you plz have a look at this [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/67722472/download-a-file-from-sharepoint-using-c-sharp-to-default-download-location-in-br)