# Download a file from SharePoint via http request - Xamarin

Tags: c#, sharepoint, xamarin.forms, httprequest, office365

I want to download an Excel-File, which is stored on SharePoint in the Folder "Shared Documents" to a phone.
I checked out the Microsoft documentation on [http requests](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sharepoint/dev/sp-add-ins/complete-basic-operations-using-sharepoint-rest-endpoints), but they don't explain how to download files.

I still used their code snippet and tried to figure it out myself, however, I'm getting the following error: "System.Net.WebException  Message=The remote server returned an error: (401) Unauthorized."

This is the code i tried out:

```
HttpWebRequest endpointRequest =
  (HttpWebRequest)HttpWebRequest.Create("https:<site-url>.com/_api/web/GetFileByServerRelativeUrl('/Shared%20Documents/test.xlsx')/$value");
endpointRequest.Method = "GET";
endpointRequest.Accept = "application/json;odata=verbose";
endpointRequest.Headers.Add("Authorization",
  "Bearer " + accessToken);
HttpWebResponse endpointResponse =
  (HttpWebResponse)endpointRequest.GetResponse();
```

test.xlsx is the file i want to download.

I'm aware that a [similar question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39338467/download-a-file-from-sharepoint) has been asked before, but the answer didn't work for me. Other answers linked to Microsoft documentation pages that sadly don't exist anymore.
It would be really great if someone could point out how to properly do this.

Comment: how are you generating `accessToken`?

Comment: I'm using the Microsoft Graph API, here is the tutorial i followed:https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/tutorials/xamarin

Comment: does that token work with other requests?  Have you tried using that url in the browser to verify that it does what you want?

Comment: Yes! I tried the url in the browser and it downloaded the file. But a different request like:   "http://<site url>/_api/web/lists");
gives me the same error.

Comment: try https://sharepoint.stackexchange.com

Comment: Have  a look at this: https://www.example-code.com/csharp/sharepoint_download_file.asp

Answer (score 0):

Its super easy with [Flurl](https://www.nuget.org/packages/Flurl.Http/3.0.0-pre2) :

```
var path = await "http://files.foo.com/image.jpg"
    .DownloadFileAsync("c:\\downloads", filename);
```